# Javascript to find a given variable value's position in one array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (array1 and array2), that match indices and sizes, but have different corresponding values. I want to use a single-valued variable (x) whose value exists in array1 to find the index position from array1 and then return the value in the same position from array2.

The values in the arrays are not always single-valued as well.

An example of array1 may have in one value:

array1 = [10, 15, 20, 27]

array2 = [up, down, left, right]

I want to use if x = down, return 15.

```html
var x = PriPosition;
var array1 = Amts;
var array2 = Positions;
var y;

for(I=0;I<array2;i++)
{
   if(array2[I] == x)
   {
      y = array1[I];
      break;
   }
}
y;
```

This function has the variables built from a report except for "y". I used the variables to shorten the real names.

When this javascript is ran, the results are blank with or without the "y;". I have also tried the indexOf() function.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: When you are writing a question, it is helpful if you use real code for your expected inputs and outputs. I don't know what this means: "line 1: 10,15,20,27 ...". Try this:
`array1 = [1, 2, 3]`   
`array2 = [4, 5, 6]`   
expected output: `[...]`

Answer (score 1):

I got indexOf to work. Please comment if code isn’t what you need.

```
x = “Foo”
var array1 = [“Foo”, “Bar”, 0, true];
var array2 = [false, “Foo”, 2, “Bar”];
var y = array2[array1.indexOf(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks, we're close! The line is still blank. I am using a reporting tool called Informer. I will keep experimenting to see if I get success.

Comment: What happens if you create a new js file with my code and run it independently of your existing code. Does it work then?

Comment: You're right, i should have tried that... I'll see about possibly contacting Support Monday for a product-specific question. Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason the reporting tool is showing blank output is because the two arrays are multi-dimensional. Is there a way in javascript to search for a value in array1 to return the value in array2?

Comment: Another point is the report output may have some lines with a multi-dimensional array and some lines a normal array, and some lines will be single-valued. Thanks for any insight...

Comment: Here is a screenshot of value x - https://imgur.com/2sCUxQ1
Here is a screenshot of array2 - https://imgur.com/ttgX7Qh
array1 has a similar index, but numerical values with array1 (not pictured)

Comment: Could you edit your questions with examples of all the different types of input, and some possible values of arr1 and arr2?

Comment: This is solved -- thanks John AZ1 -- your help did come into play. The reason why Informer didn't work at first was due to the arrays being multidimensional. Along with Support, we had to first convert the md arrays into single dimensional arrays, then used indexOf (indexOf does not work on md arrays).